# onEdit not triggering when pasting data

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Using onEdit trigger to create a folder in Drive. Works when typing data into field, but does not trigger when I paste data. Updated with recommended changes, still does not trigger with pasted data.

```
function createSpreadsheetEditTrigger() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1IzR2ceVKG8SSTDHMx-N6NCuzzUHGyAOHHsykT7r-xcg');
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('addFolder')
      .forSpreadsheet(ss)
      .onEdit()
      .create();
}

function addFolder(e) {
  // helps with verifying where data was entered
  // in the sheet
  const myNewColumn = e.range.getColumn()
  const myNewRow = e.range.getRow()
  const value = e.range.getValues().flat().join("");
  
  if (myNewColumn == 1 && myNewRow > 2 && value.includes(",")) { 
    // capture first and last name entered
    const firstName = e.value.split(", ")[1]
    const lastName = e.value.split(", ")[0]
  
    // identify the folder where
    // new student folders will exist
    const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1l_dYf74ITGiUzu10t72XCig2HWL_Q0PH') 
    
    // create student's new folder
    const newFolder = folder.createFolder(`${lastName}, ${firstName} - Evidence`)
    const newFolderId = newFolder.getId()
    const specificNewFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(newFolderId)
  
    // add subfolders to student folder
    const ela = newFolder.createFolder("ELA")
    const math = newFolder.createFolder("Math")
    const behavior = newFolder.createFolder("Behavior")
  
    // create form
    const form = FormApp.create(`${lastName}, ${firstName} Feedback Form`);
    form.setTitle(`${lastName}, ${firstName}`)
      .setDescription('Progress on Goal Feedback Form')
```

Comment: The code is incomplete

Comment: Thanks, I have added a more complete question.

Comment: The closing `}` of `addFolder` function declaration is missing, maybe also other things are missing too.

Answer (score 2):

When the value is copied and pasted, the event object doesn't include `value`. I think that this is the reason of your issue. So in order to work for both manual input and copy&paste input of values, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
if (myNewColumn == 1 && myNewRow > 2 && e.value.includes(",")) {
```

#### To:

```
const value = e.range.getValues().flat().join("");  // Added
if (myNewColumn == 1 && myNewRow > 2 && value.includes(",")) {  // Modified
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the support. I have implemented the changes, but it still does not trigger on paste. Should I just run the trigger manually?

Comment: @Carlos LaGrange Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, from `I have implemented the changes, but it still does not trigger on paste.`, I cannot replicate your situation. So can you provide the detail information including your current script and flow for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. By the way, I cannot understand what you want to do from `Should I just run the trigger manually?`. Can I also ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: https://script.google.com/d/1UdlgOQ0OSKsYydLowVnVTgQG4OGHH0kkBDd1EcpkG7pRFTpGAqIjMLDs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LSVI_C3QhpDUsx4TMBOFAQtUSf_9Me5XBwPbkuqu-a8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I truly appreciate your kindness. I have linked to the code and sheet above. As you can see the code works well when I manually type a Full Name into A3, but when I copy and paste a name into A4, the code does not run.

Comment: @Carlos LaGrange Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your additional information, when I tested my proposed script using your shared Spreadsheet, I could confirm that when I manually put "sample, sample" to the cell "A3" and I copied the cell "A3" to the cell "A4", the if statement of `myNewColumn == 1 && myNewRow > 2 && value.includes(",")` is `true`. You can confirm about this with the script of `console.log(myNewColumn == 1 && myNewRow > 2 && value.includes(","))`. How about this?

Comment: @Carlos LaGrange In this case, the script is required to be the container-bound script of the Spreadsheet and `addFolder` is required to be installed as the installable OnEdit trigger. Please confirm this again.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice. I do not have the technical experience to fully understand what you are asking. I will need to hire someone to make this work, but I very much appreciate all of your advice.

Comment: @Carlos LaGrange Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. I asked that where is your script? For example, you open the Spreadsheet and open the script editor from the Spreadsheet? Or you directly open the script editor on Google Drive?

Answer (score 0):

The property `value` of the edit event object only is included when a single cell is edited and it's not blank.

Considering the above you should improve your code to use `e.range.getValues()` instead of e.value.

Comment: Thank you! I did change the code but it still does not trigger on paste...